# Is there any way to access Yahoo IMAP with Oauth2 for new applications?

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-mail

I'm looking for a way to allow Yahoo application to read user's emails over IMAP. It works well for old applications (that were created before Yahoo Mail API has deprecated), but trying to access IMAP for new applications gives me an error

```
[AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] (#AUTH007) Bad scope.
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to add a correct scope for accessing IMAP for new applications. During creation of the app, I was not given a choice to add scope with name even looking like 'mail'.

Is Yahoo API just broken or there is some tricky way to work around?

Answer (score 0):

Contact imap-service@yahoo-inc.com

With your Yahoo.com email address and

1. Brief description of your product.
2. How will your product use Yahoo user's email content?
3. How will your product help Yahoo mail users?
4. What market do you serve?
5. What is your product's userbase?